# Use RankX based on a measure with dynamic max date

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a data set of game logs for a basketball season. I  want to do a ranking for a statistic comparing all teams, but only up to the current date of that specific row. Since not every team plays every day, the current row should be the max date and it should rank based on the most recent value up to that date. I have a measure that does the correct calculation:

```
LatestTmDVP =
VAR thisdate =
    MAX ( [DATE] )
VAR maxdate =
    CALCULATE ( MAX ( [DATE] ), ALLSELECTED ( 'NBA-PLAYER-FEED'[DATE] ) )
VAR result =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'NBA-PLAYER-FEED'[TmDVPoToDt] ),
        'NBA-PLAYER-FEED'[DATE] = maxdate
    )
RETURN
    IF ( thisdate = maxdate, result )
```

If I put this in a report with a date slicer, I can see that it is working correctly:

[image]

So I need to get this measure into a column, with the max date set as the date of the current row, and then do a rank based on that, but I just can't get the RankX syntax right for this. Appreciate any help!

Comment: Can you send some sample data and expected output of the same please..

Comment: So I ended up just giving up on this. I'm nearly certain it could be done in a formula for a column, but I ended up just creating a new sheet that has every date and team, regardless if they play or not, and looks up the current day's value, and if there is none, the prior day's value, etc. etc. So I then have a table with the most recent values. Essentially it's just brute-forcing what surely could be more elegant, but it works